# Why folding circuits are used in ADC?

Tags: adc

Can somebody explain why folding circuits are used in ADC.  I know that they are used to estimate the noise but exactly how is this done.  Also I would like to know in what kind of ADC is this used and do they suffer from problems such as non monotonic, DNL or INL.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_ADC#Folding_ADC

Comment: "*I know that they are used to estimate the noise but exactly how is this done. Also I would like to know in what kind of ADC is this used and do they suffer from problems such as non monotonic, DNL or INL.*", I didn't answer this... so you shouldn't accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are talking about how a folding circuit is made. - This will be a half answer, in the way it will only answer your first half of question*s*.

> In this answer I will call op-amps and comparators for op-amps. It should be comparators because they have higher bandwidth, but some comparators got open collector at its output which this answer ignores (*infinite* output impedance when trying to source current). This answer depends on "op-amps" that can give rail to rail output with zero output impedance. Some op-amps can't reach VDD or GND, but they at least have reasonably low output impedance, so their term will be more correct in my opinion.

---

Hmm, I believe this is what I've got in some of my folders...

I realized that a simple comparator is a 1 bit ADC that tells you if a voltage is above or below half of VDD. So if I *somehow* could add another op-amp that would only compare the 1/4 and the 3/4 levels then I would have a 2 bit ADC. In other words I would reuse, aka *fold*, the second op-amp.. or make some circuit right before its input so it could be used twice.

And once you have a 2 bit op-amp you simply add a 3rd that takes care of 1/8, 3/8, 5/8 and 7/8. So Here it's folding twice, so I am using the same op-amp 4 times.

Here's a circuit that shows how 4 op-amps can work together to give you a 4 bit ADC.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%202.1831051418620846%2061%205%2050%0AR%20-256%20192%20-256%20160%200%200%2040%2016%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-192%20240%20-192%20336%200%0Ar%20-160%20336%20-112%20336%200%2010000%0Aw%20-112%20336%20-32%20336%202%0Aw%20-192%20336%20-192%20432%200%0A172%20-192%20240%20-192%20160%200%206%208.4%2020%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Ar%20-112%20256%20-112%20336%200%2020000%0Aw%20-224%20272%20-224%20368%200%0Aw%20-224%20368%20-32%20368%200%0Aa%20-192%20256%20-112%20256%200%2016%200%201000000%208.4%208%0Aa%20-32%20352%2048%20352%200%2016%200%201000000%205.599986666666666%208%0Aa%20176%20448%20256%20448%200%2016%200%201000000%207.085737140761903%208%0Aw%20-192%20432%200%20432%200%0Aw%2096%20432%20176%20432%202%0Aw%20-112%20256%2096%20256%200%0Aw%2096%20352%2096%20256%200%0Aw%20-224%20368%20-224%20464%200%0Aw%2048%20240%2048%20352%200%0Aw%20256%20240%20256%20448%200%0Aw%2048%20432%2096%20432%200%0Aw%20-224%20464%20176%20464%200%0Ar%2096%20352%2096%20432%200%2020000%0Ar%200%20432%2048%20432%200%2010000%0Ar%2048%20352%2048%20432%200%2040000%0Ag%20-256%20352%20-256%20368%200%0Ar%20-256%20272%20-256%20192%200%2010000%0Ar%20-256%20352%20-256%20272%200%2010000%0Aw%20-224%20272%20-256%20272%200%0Aw%20-224%20272%20-192%20272%200%0Aw%20-192%20336%20-160%20336%200%0Ar%20304%20448%20304%20528%200%2040000%0Ar%20208%20528%20256%20528%200%2010000%0Ar%20352%20448%20352%20528%200%2020000%0Aw%20-224%20560%20432%20560%200%0Aw%20304%20528%20352%20528%200%0Aw%20512%20240%20512%20544%200%0Aw%20352%20528%20432%20528%202%0Aa%20432%20544%20512%20544%200%2016%200%201000000%207.6800274253968395%208%0Ar%20256%20448%20256%20528%200%2080000%0Aw%2048%20352%20304%20352%200%0Aw%20304%20352%20304%20448%200%0Aw%2096%20256%20352%20256%200%0Aw%20352%20448%20352%20256%200%0Aw%20-192%20432%20-192%20528%200%0Aw%20-192%20528%20208%20528%200%0Aw%20-224%20464%20-224%20560%200%0Aw%20304%20528%20256%20528%200%0Ar%20-112%20208%20-112%20240%200%201000%0Aw%20-112%20240%20-112%20256%200%0A162%20-112%20176%20-112%20208%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0AR%20-112%20176%20-112%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%2048%20176%2048%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A162%2048%20176%2048%20208%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%2048%20208%2048%20240%200%201000%0AR%20256%20176%20256%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A162%20256%20176%20256%20208%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20256%20208%20256%20240%200%201000%0AR%20512%20176%20512%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A162%20512%20176%20512%20208%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20512%20208%20512%20240%200%201000%0Ao%205%204%200%204098%2020%200.0015625%200%202%205%203%0Ao%2048%204%200%204098%2020%200.00625%201%202%2048%203%0Ao%2017%204%200%204098%2020%200.00625%201%202%2017%203%0Ao%2018%204%200%204098%2020%200.00625%201%202%2018%203%0Ao%2035%204%200%204098%2020%200.00625%201%202%2035%203%0Ao%201%204%200%204098%2020%200.00078125%202%202%201%203%0Ao%203%204%200%204098%2020%200.00009765625%202%202%203%203%0Ao%2013%204%200%204098%2020%200.00009765625%202%202%2013%203%0Ao%2036%204%200%204098%2017.27962870443171%200.0001%202%202%2036%203%0A) if you want to play around with it.

- The left graph is the 9.8 V input at the top left which is the voltage you are trying to quantize.
- The middle graph is \$\bar Y_3 \bar Y_2 \bar Y_1 \bar Y_0\$.
- The right graph is the folding taking place. It's each op-amps negative input.

So at the negative input of every op-amp (except for the first), I subtract the result from the previous op-amp. So in this case the Vref is 16 V, and it's 4 bit ADC => 1 volt per bit. This means that if I am below 8 volts, then the upper left op-amp will output a high voltage, this will make it so the second leftmost op-amp triggers at 4 V. When I increase the input voltage above 8 volts then the leftmost op-amp output 0 V, this subtracts some volts to the second leftmost op-amp so that it will trigger again at 12 volts. The same idea is used on the other stages.

In the comments, Bruce Abbot posted this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_ADC#Folding_ADC), right above where that link points to there's a graph. See how they are only getting a 2 bit resolution with 4 op-amps(comparators?), while I am getting 4 bit resolution with 4 op-amps.

---

This should get you set in *how* folding works, at least in this case. And *why* I use it.