# Convert PWM signal to multiple switching outputs

Tags: digital-logic, pwm

I'm looking for an IC that will perform a specific function. I have a device that I can output a PWM signal of varying duty cycles (12V Nominal).

I want to use that device to control a switching circuit, with each output controlling an on/off state of a light. The output pattern would be a binary value proportional to the PWM mark/space ratio.

For example, if I output a 50% duty cycle, I would get the output 10000000. Light 8 lights up, the rest are off (power coming from elsewhere, of course). If I output a 99-100% duty cycle, I would want the output 11111111, all 8 lights on.

I'm actually only using 6 lights, so 6 outputs would be fine. I could even make it work on 4 outputs (100% PWM again being all outputs on) and add additional logic afterwards if I had to. Just need something to convert the PWM to discrete digital switching outputs, essentially.

Does such a device exist somewhere? I haven't been able to come up with anything remotely close while searching.

Comment: You can repurpose a small microcontroller with enough I/Os and an available timer/pin interrupt, where you measure the duty cycle of your PWM signal (of course, after dividing the voltage from 12V to one appropriate for your microcontroller) and output an appropriate digital output. Alternatively, it might be possible for you to low-pass-filter the signal to an analog voltage and pass it through an ADC, but this seems like a hack to me.

Comment: sound like a job for a microcontroller

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a binary pattern displayed from 0 to \$ 2^n -1 \$ where \$n\$ is the number of bits? Or do you want a bar-graph display like an audio level meter?

Comment: These sort of minority, specific functions are mopped up by microcontrollers or, with highest versatility, CPLDs or FPGAs. I'd use a CPLD myself but it really depends on what you're familiar and competent with or most ready to learn, what's already in your circuit or would benefit from this addition etc. Then there's approvals you might have to work to professionally that would steer your decision.

Comment: I should've specified I'm trying to avoid using a micro. I'm aware of that solution, but looking for something quicker and cheaper, if possible. I was looking for a binary pattern, not necessarily a bar-graph. An though I was thinking (2^n) - 1 combinations as a default, I realize that is way more than I actually need for this application. When it comes down to it, this very specific pattern I could use 2 3-segment bar graphs to achieve my goal.

Comment: What frequency is your PWM waveform running at?

Comment: It's variable up to 1 KHz

Comment: I should have said: please edit this extra information into your question, don't post it all in comments. Otherwise, other learners have to piece the question together by trawling all this lot. Thanks.

Comment: "It's variable up to 1 KHz" - Be more specific. What is the _minimum_ PWM frequency? How quickly must the lights to respond to changing PWM ratio? Exactly what is the application?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be very closely related to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351240/why-folding-circuits-are-used-in-adc/351287#351287).

It's essentially an ADC, but you said you don't want to use microcontrollers (**you haven't given any proper reason for this**), so here it is solved with op-amps.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2013.097415321081861%2055%205%2050%0AR%20-272%2096%20-272%2064%200%200%2040%204%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-208%20144%20-208%20240%200%0Ar%20-176%20240%20-128%20240%200%2010000%0Aw%20-128%20240%20-48%20240%202%0Aw%20-208%20240%20-208%20336%200%0Ar%20-128%20160%20-128%20240%200%2020000%0Aw%20-240%20176%20-240%20272%200%0Aw%20-240%20272%20-48%20272%200%0Aa%20-208%20160%20-128%20160%200%204%200%201000000%202.2640993301834493%202%0Aa%20-48%20256%2032%20256%200%204%200%201000000%201.5093907501446269%202%0Aa%20160%20352%20240%20352%200%204%200%201000000%201.8651990796846782%202%0Aw%20-208%20336%20-16%20336%200%0Aw%2080%20336%20160%20336%202%0Aw%20-128%20160%2080%20160%200%0Aw%2080%20256%2080%20160%200%0Aw%20-240%20272%20-240%20368%200%0Aw%2032%20160%2032%20256%200%0Aw%20240%20160%20240%20352%200%0Aw%2032%20336%2080%20336%200%0Aw%20-240%20368%20160%20368%200%0Ar%2080%20256%2080%20336%200%2020000%0Ar%20-16%20336%2032%20336%200%2010000%0Ar%2032%20256%2032%20336%200%2040000%0Ag%20-272%20256%20-272%20272%200%0Ar%20-272%20176%20-272%2096%200%202000%0Ar%20-272%20256%20-272%20176%200%202000%0Aw%20-240%20176%20-272%20176%200%0Aw%20-240%20176%20-208%20176%200%0Aw%20-208%20240%20-176%20240%200%0Ar%20288%20352%20288%20432%200%2040000%0Ar%20192%20432%20240%20432%200%2010000%0Ar%20336%20352%20336%20432%200%2020000%0Aw%20-240%20464%20416%20464%200%0Aw%20288%20432%20336%20432%200%0Aw%20496%20160%20496%20448%200%0Aw%20336%20432%20416%20432%202%0Aa%20416%20448%20496%20448%200%204%200%201000000%202.0075200394451684%202%0Ar%20240%20352%20240%20432%200%2080000%0Aw%2032%20256%20288%20256%200%0Aw%20288%20256%20288%20352%200%0Aw%2080%20160%20336%20160%200%0Aw%20336%20352%20336%20160%200%0Aw%20-208%20336%20-208%20432%200%0Aw%20-208%20432%20192%20432%200%0Aw%20-240%20368%20-240%20464%200%0Aw%20288%20432%20240%20432%200%0A172%20-352%20-96%20-384%20-96%200%206%202.25%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Ac%20-288%20-64%20-224%20-64%200%200.000001%20-2.2977044457319304%0Aa%20-352%20-112%20-272%20-112%200%204%200%201000000%202.459999747662514%202.25%0AR%20-352%20-128%20-384%20-128%200%204%201000%202%202%200%200.5%0Ar%20-224%20-64%20-224%20-112%200%2010000%0Ag%20-288%20-64%20-288%20-48%200%0A162%20-128%2048%20-128%2096%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20-128%2096%20-128%20160%200%201000%0AR%20-128%2048%20-128%2016%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%2032%2048%2032%2016%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2032%2096%2032%20160%200%201000%0A162%2032%2048%2032%2096%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0AR%20240%2048%20240%2016%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20240%2096%20240%20160%200%201000%0A162%20240%2048%20240%2096%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0AR%20496%2048%20496%2016%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20496%2096%20496%20160%200%201000%0A162%20496%2048%20496%2096%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20-272%20-112%20-224%20-112%200%0Ar%20-224%20-64%20-224%20-16%200%2010000%0Ag%20-288%20-16%20-288%200%200%0Ac%20-288%20-16%20-224%20-16%200%201e-7%20-2.2641219711767513%0Aa%20-208%2016%20-208%2096%200%204%200%201000000%202.2640993301834493%202.2641219711767513%0Aw%20-208%2096%20-208%20144%200%0Aw%20-208%2096%20-160%2096%200%0Aw%20-160%2096%20-160%2016%200%0Aw%20-160%2016%20-192%2016%202%0Ax%20-275%20-124%20-216%20-121%204%2024%20PWM%0Aw%20-224%20-16%20-224%2016%200%0Ao%2046%2016%200%204098%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2046%203%0Ao%2064%2016%200%204098%2010%200.00078125%201%202%2064%203%0Ao%2072%2016%200%204098%205%200.00009765625%202%202%2072%203%0Ao%2013%2016%200%204098%200.0000762939453125%200.00078125%203%202%2013%203%0Ao%2038%2016%200%204098%205%200.0001953125%203%202%2038%203%0Ao%2017%2016%200%204098%205%200.00009765625%203%202%2017%203%0Ao%2034%2016%200%204098%200.0000762939453125%200.0125%203%202%2034%203%0A) to this circuit if you want to mess around with it.

- The leftmost graph is the duty-cycle of the PWM.
- The second graph is the PWM that you will be sending into this circuit.
- The third graph is the filtered PWM.
- The fourth graph is the inverted bit values of the analog value.
- The red LED's in the image shows the bit value representation of the analog voltage which in this case is the filtered PWM.

It says *PWM* in the image, that is where you connect your PWM. The op-amp and the 1 kHz sawtooth with the 2.3 V is just me generating PWM in the simulator.

So first I filter the PWM to get the average voltage of the PWM. Then I feed it into an op-amp acting as a buffer and then I simply use other op-amps in a folding set up to act as ADC's (Analog to Digital Converter). If you want to understand how the folding works then I recommend you to either click the simulation link and see for yourself, or click the link to the other answer.

In this case it says \$1001_2\$, the voltage reference is 4 V. So the leftmost bit says that it's above 2 V. The LSB says that it's above 0.25 V. And 2+0.25 = 2.25, the input is 2.3 V, so it makes sense.

The duty-cycle is in this case \$\frac{2.3}{4}=57.5\%\$. If your PWM is 8 bit then 57.5% maps to \$0.575×2^8\approx 147\$.

If you want to see the bit pattern of \$1001_2\$ from 147 then I can tell you this. It is a 4 bit ADC, and 8 bit PWM divided by 4 bit ADC = 16. So every 16th value of your PWM will increment this ADC. So let's divide 147 by 16 and see what we get. \$\frac{147}{16}=9.1875\approx 9\$. If you know your bits then you also know that \$9_{10}=1001_2\$. So it looks like it makes sense.

---

If you are going to physically build this circuit, then you're better off using a microcontroller and be done with it. That way you don't even need to use PWM, you can actually use a shift register to carry out your data. That's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Bar graph display controller such as the [TI LM3914](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf), this will give you 1 of 10 or Line to 10 displays.
[image]

There are many different bar graph display controllers but they all work in a similar fashion.

You can use an RC filter to produce a DC signal from your PWM signal.

Comment: That's an interesting potential solution. I didn't know these ICs existed. I'll look into it. I'm not 100% sure it will work but it's promising.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would be achieved by low-pass filtering the PWM and putting an ADC with parallel output (like ADC0820) after. This would be a rather simple solution.

**However**: this smells like a bad overall solution for a problem that should maybe be analysed more globally. Because such a solution implies, for example, that, when you want to go from all lights off to just the MSB lamp on (output 10000000), the system will go through all states from 00000000 to 10000000, which means all lamps will flash during the transition. Also, if you have some noise on the PWM output, the lamps may just blink randomly, even those who are supposed to be off.

So I would really suggest to take a step back, tell us where this PWM come from and maybe rethink the whole solution with appropriate means.